# powershell function does not work

Tags: powershell, alias

I'm new to powershell scripting. scan a file with `windowsdefender` from command line.
what I'm doing wrong?

```
function scan { Start-Process "C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -Scan -ScanType 3 -File $args[0] }
```

> C:\Program Files\Windows Defender>MpCmdRun -scan -scantype 3 -file *.dll
> Scan starting...
> CmdTool: Failed with hr = 0x80508023. Check C:\Users\exp\AppData\Local\Temp\MpCmdRun.log for more information
> MpCmdRun: Command Line: "C:\program files\windows defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -scan -scantype 3 -file *.dll
> Start Time: ‎ma. ‎oct. ‎06 ‎2020 23:36:36

> MpEnsureProcessMitigationPolicy: hr = 0x1
> Starting RunCommandScan.
> INFO: ScheduleJob is not set. Skipping signature update.
> Scanning path as file: *.dll.
> Start: MpScan(MP_FEATURE_SUPPORTED, dwOptions=16385, path *.dll, DisableRemediation = 0, BootSectorScan = 0, Timeout in days = 1)
> MpScan() started
> Warning: MpScan() encounter errror. hr = 0x80508023
> MpScan() was completed
> ERROR: MpScan(dwOptions=16385) Completion Failed 80508023
> MpCmdRun: End Time: ‎ma. ‎oct. ‎06 ‎2020 23:36:36

---

Comment: have you made the CONTENT of the function work yet? that doesn't look right for some reason ... [*frown*]

Comment: look at the argumentlist option.

Comment: oh its a problem with the command not the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your function you need to pass the cmd arguments in via -ArgumentList

```
function scan { Start-Process "C:\program files\windows defender\mpcmdrun.exe" -ArgumentList "-Scan -ScanType 3 -File $($args[0])" }
```

There is a PowerShell Cmdlet to do this already:

```
Start-MpScan -ScanPath C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -ScanType CustomScan
```